# Post-apocalyptic novel series with female main protagonist who uses a bow and arrow

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, post-apocalyptic

Sometime in the 1980s I read a series that took place in the States just before the bombs fall, and then continues as these youths (I think it's two guys and a girl) start exploring what is left of their world. Two of them are brother and sister.

- They encounter mutated animals of various sorts, plus different survivors. The storyline seems similar to "Children of Dust" but, there is no family in the shelter with them.
- I think there were 3 books in the series and the series title had something to do with nuclear fallout.
- The main character was a girl. When they first come up from the shelter, they are attacked by mutated dogs. She uses a bow and arrow? or a rifle from the shelter?

Its killing me trying to remember the title... please help :)

Comment: Has elements of the bridge series between the Knight of the Word and Shannara by Terry Brooks.

Comment: I read these in Grade school... back in the 80's. Narrative is entirely about post nuke attack on North American Soil.

Comment: Sounds a little like Brother in the Land, but I don't remember any mutated dogs or bows and arrows, so leaving it as just a comment.